# How to prove divisibility test for $4$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $n$ be an integer, $4|n$ if and only if the last two digit of $n$ are divisible by $4$.

I tried to use $4|n$ implies that $n\equiv 0 \pmod4$

Comment: $4|124$ but $4\nmid2$ while $2$ is one of the last two digits. Your question should be reformulated.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it's answer is explained in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule#Divisibility_by_4).

Comment: @Jykri that is not a criteria for closure!! In any case Wikipedia's proofs are often very difficult to understand!

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Wikipedia does not formally derive it.

Comment: This is also [a duplicate of this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/676431/11619).

Comment: @Mathmo123: I disagree. At least in a case like this when the rule has been explained and proved in many junior high level books and the question asker shows no effort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$M=\sum_{r=0}^na_r10^r\equiv a_0+10a_1+10^2a_2+\cdots+10^ma_m\pmod{10^{m+1}}$$ for integer $m\ge0$

In fact,we can prove that $\displaystyle 2^s|M,$ if the last $s(\ge1)$ digits are divisible by $2^s$

Here $s=2$ i.e., $$M=\sum_{r=0}^na_r10^r\equiv a_0+10a_1\pmod{100}\equiv a_0+10a_1\pmod4$$

We can further generalize this to any base $b$ and divisibility for their divisors

Comment: This is the best proof on this page

Answer (score 5):

***Hint:***

By the Division Algorithm for any given integer $n$ there is an integer $k$ such that $$n = 100 + k $$ Also note that $4 \ | \ 100$

Comment: A more general version that applies here would be $n = m \cdot 100 + k$ where $m$ is some integer and $0 \leq k \leq 99$ is at most a 2-digit integer.