# Why is every number which ends in 5 divisible by 5?

Tags: arithmetic

Is there more of an answer to this which is more than just 'it does'?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/898096/how-to-prove-divisibility-test-for-4

Comment: It's because $5$ divides $10$, and every number which ends in $5$ is $5$ plus powers of $10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's only true in decimal ;)

That is the hint of observing this property:
all digits that are in front add factors of 10, which is divisible by 10 and therefor also by 5. And that doesn't change anything in divisibility.

Comment: No, it's true in any radix that is divisible by $\,5.\ \ $

Comment: True, so it's also true in quindecimal :)